# missing PageAsyncTask(Func<object, CancellationToken, Task>) constructor

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

Why isn't there a constructor for `PageAsyncTask` that takes an object as an async state? The old overloads had it already, so why is it missing now - the `Task.ContinueWith` supports an aysnc state object in .Net 4.5 so I see absolutely no reason for this oversight (`Task.Run` missing it as well is another puzzling one).

I was pretty used to it before - so is there any alternative other than declaring it as a private field on the `Page`, or using an async lambda / anonymous delegate and capturing it in a closure?